# How do I spawn a Creeper spawner?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I make a Creeper spawner in Single player?

Comment: Have you done any research for yourself?  You'll find that people here are more receptive if you show that you've at least tried to solve your own problem first.

Comment: what version of minecraft?

Comment: Is this with mods or no mods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite easy:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:"Creeper"}
```

Of course you can replace `Creeper` with any other type of mob, like `Pig` or `Zombie`.

Comment: It works perfectly fine in Minecraft 1.8.8, I just checked

Comment: Oh right then, sorry my source must have been incorrect. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

Type `/give (username here) minecraft:mob_spawner` and then get a creeper spawn egg out of creative and right click the spawner with it then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a mob spawner block (that spawns creepers), just type `/give @p mob_spawner`, then place and right-click with a creeper egg.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

The easiest way would be too give yourself a creeper spawner, which can be done by:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:"Creeper"}
```

One alternative though could be too set up a command block clock which spawns in a creeper every [number of seconds]. This can be done with:

```
/spawnmob <mob> [amount of mobs]
```

Another way if command blocks aren't your thing would be too once again set up a redstone clock, and connect it too a dispenser full of creeper eggs. While this would not be infinite (at least without commands filling the dispenser up every time one leaves), it would certainly spawn 621 creepers before a refill was required, all without using command blocks.

But if you don't mind the mod option, a very good mod that can do this is the "Too Many Items" mod, which can also do a whole lot more which I'm sure you'll find very interesting.

Comment: Using commands you can make the spawner spawn any type of entity, or even multiple types of entities. This is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, my source of information must have been incorrect. I've fixed it now though!

Comment: `/spawnmob` does not exist in vanilla Minecraft. There is a `/summon` command, but that will only ever summon a single entity.

Comment: Yeah, I realise now that this whole answer is complete garbage. please delete if you can, or edit if you think it can be salvaged. My source was really incorrect.

Comment: You should be able to delete your own answer btw.

Comment: Yeah, I realised this, but I the end I've decided not to delete.